# Regex Lookahead and lookbehind multiple times in Python

Tags: python, arrays, regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds

I have the input formatted as below (txt1):

`txt1 = "[('1','Hello is 1)people 2)animals'), ('People are 1) hello 2) animals'), ('a')]"`

I want to extract it in the following format-

`[['1','Hello is 1)people 2)animals'],['People are 1) hello 2) animals'],['a']]`

So, basically, I want the information within the parentheses. But I haven't been able to do that. Also, I have used the Lookahead and Lookbehind to avoid splitting by the numbers- '1)' or '2)' which happened earlier when I went a simple statement of `re.split('[\(\)\[\]]`

I have been trying a **findall** function first to check what I am getting.

`r = re.findall(r'\((?=\').*(?<=\')\)(?=\,)', txt1)`

I have been getting-

`["('1','Hello is 1)people 2)animals'), ('People are 1) hello 2) animals')"]`

It seems like it is ignoring the middle parenthesis. What can I do to get the result that I need?

Thank you.

**Note:**

For the split function, which I intend to use to get the desired output, I am getting this-

`r = re.split(r'\((?=\').*(?<=\')\)(?=\,)', txt1)`

`['[', ", ('a')]"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why regex?

```
import ast
[list(x) if isinstance(x, tuple) else [x] for x in ast.literal_eval(txt1)]
# => [['1', 'Hello is 1)people 2)animals'], ['People are 1) hello 2) animals'], ['a']]
```

If you insist on regular expressions, this should work unless the strings contain escaped quotes:

```
[re.findall(r"'[^']*'", x) for x in re.findall(r"\(('[^']*'(?:,\s*'[^']*')*)\)", txt1)]
# => [["'1'", "'Hello is 1)people 2)animals'"], ["'People are 1) hello 2) animals'"], ["'a'"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without having to use `regex`:

```
txt1 = "[('1','Hello is 1)people 2)animals'), ('People are 1) hello 2) animals'), ('a')]"
replace_pairs = {
    "('": "'",
    "'), ": '#',
    '[': '',
    ']': '',
    "'": '',
}
for k, v in replace_pairs.items():
    txt1 = txt1.replace(k, v)

txt1 = txt1[:-1].split('#') # the last char is a paranthesis
print([i.split(',') for i in txt1])
```

Output:

```
[['1', 'Hello is 1)people 2)animals'], ['People are 1) hello 2) animals'], ['a']]
```

Note: This may not work if the input is more complicated than what you've shown here.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with pattern `\(([^(]+)\)`

Explanation:

`\(` - match `(` literally

`(...)` - capturing group

`[^(]+` - match one or more characters other from `(`

`\)` - match `)` literally

And use replace pattern: `[\1]`, which puts first capturing group (backreference `\1`) inside square brackets.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/W2zpKQ/1)

Comment: Can you please explain what is ` [^(]+ ` is doing here? I believe this is for the detection of " ( " character however many times it appears. But isn't that achieved with " \( " earlier?

Comment: @SantoshPavan No, it is explained in answer: matches one or more character other from `(`

Comment: In that case, shouldn't it work for the input ` ('1', 'Hello is (1) people 2)animals') ` as well? Because it is detecting `(1) people 2) animals') ` instead of detecting the parentheses from ` ('1',  'Hello is (1) people 2) animals') `.

Comment: @SantoshPavan No, because of `(1)` inside first entry

Comment: Could you please tell me what would be the regex for the other input that I've mentioned? I want to understand it more. I am trying to come up with one but couldn't. Thank you.